# Shared tooltips on a pie in a donut?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm fussing with a pie in a donut in Highcharts, and I can't seem to get either a legend or a shared tooltip to appear. It works fine [with non-shared tooltips](http://jsfiddle.net/JNMWZ/1/):

```
tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.point.name + ': ' +this.y 
                    + ' units (' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 0) + '%)'
                ;  

            },
        },
```

But if I try to transform that into a [shared tooltip](http://jsfiddle.net/JNMWZ/3/), nothing appears.

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var s = this.series.name + this.point.name;
            $.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
                s += point.name + ' ' + point.y + ' ' + point.percentage;
            });
            return s;
        },
        shared: true
    },
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Doesn't look like this.points is defined in your $.each function.

Comment: Are you trying to get a shared tooltip for the whole of each colored groups?

Comment: @KristianK. It would be kind of sweet if I could organize the shared tooltip by big buckets, but I just wanted something shared that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just took a look at your `highcharts` (`this`) object in your formatter function. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but it looks like the `highcharts` object holds a `series` array of `points`:

```
$.each(this.series.points, function (i, point) {
    s += point.name + ' ' + point.y + ' ' + point.percentage + '<br/>';
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JNMWZ/8/)

**EDIT**: Added a line break for good measure =D

Comment: hah, yeah. I needed `this.series.points` -- once I got that the need for a line break was pretty apparent.